# How to get an ID of the message I replied with command to in discord py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

So I have the code which adds reaction to the message with the specific ID. But I want to do that if I will reply to a message with this command, bot will get an ID of the message I have replied to and will react to it.
There is my "add reaction" code if you're interested. I'm super new to python and even newer to the discord bots, so sorry if it's  a dumb question.

```
@bot.command()
async def heart(ctx, msgid):
    ctx.message.id = msgid
    #await ctx.reply("Here's your reaction")
    await ctx.message.add_reaction("")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want your bot to react to **someone's else message** after replying to it with a command. You can do it by using [**message.reference**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?#discord.Message.reference).

```
@client.command()
async def reply(ctx):
    channel = ctx.channel #get channel where command was used
    msg = await channel.fetch_message(ctx.message.reference.message_id) #fetching message which command replied to
    await msg.add_reaction("") #sending reaction
```

***Example screenshot of how it works:***

[image: Screenshot example 1]

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.command
async def reply(ctx, *, args = None):
    await args.add_reaction(emoji='')
```

usage : reply messageid